# Math problem: Determine the corner radius of an inner border based on outer corner radius/thickness

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, math, geometry

Here's a math/geometry problem for the math whizzes (not my strongest subject). This is for WPF, but should be general enough to solve regardless:

I have two embedded Border elements, with the outer one having a certain corner radius, `R` and border thickness, `T`. Given these two values, what should the corner radius of the inner Border, `R'` be set to such that the two corner edges meet with no overlap or holes?

[image]

So far I've just been eyeballing it, but if someone can give me a proper formula that would be great. Respect points if you can!! ;)

Comment: This is a visual problem - if you could post a diagram of what you wanted it would probably help a lot! :)

Comment: Any reason why the obvious answer of `R' = R - T` doesn't work?

Comment: Added an illustration. @Ignacio: I do believe I tried this and it didn't work.

Comment: @Ignacio: To illustrate why it can't be R - T, imagine R and T are both 1. R' would then be 0 with this formula, but it can't be zero because zero means square corners, and R is not square. -- Then again I guess it could happen that the inner side of the radius could be square if the R is small enough or T is big enough. *shrug*

Comment: It seems to me that the inner border in the example doesn't lie correctly on the imaginary circle (the connection with the straight border isn't smooth). If it did, Ignacio's formula would work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

T'/2 + R` = R - T/2

or

For a given T, R and T' then R' = R - T/2 - T'/2

So for instance for an outer border thickness of (T=10), and radius of (R=8), and an inner border thickness of (T'=4), you'd need an inner border radius of 1.

Comment: Yes! This is it! Upon closer inspection, R - T was overlapping very slightly at my values. This formula appears to be dead on. Yay, respect points for Aviad! ++++ :)

Comment: For a specific case this formula gave me a corner radius of thickness 0. This obviously did not work, but filling in 0.01 worked a treat.

Comment: Thanks for this great formula. But what if my outer and inner thickness is different on any edge? I.e. `<Border x:Name="outerBorder" CornerRadius="5 5 2 2" BorderThickness="10 4 2 4"><Border x:Name="innerBorder" BorderThickness="3 2 3 2" /></Border>`. How is the formula to determine every corner radius for the `innerBorder` element. I have to respect two outer thickness and inner thickness for that calculation.